# Optimise multiply for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, which works fine. However, as I am very new to Python, there is still space to improve. I would like you to suggest to me the best way to handle this particular case and meanwhile, I can learn from it.

```
            # Find all methods belonging to this header
            custom_methods_of_the_current_header = [method for method in fmt_data if
                                                    method["type"] == constants.CUSTOM_METHOD and method[
                                                        "parent_id"] == header_id]
            custom_methods_of_the_current_header_ordered = []
            for i in range(1, len(ordered_list) - 1):
                for j in range(len(custom_methods_of_the_current_header)):
                    if custom_methods_of_the_current_header[j]["name"] == ordered_list[i].gg.kind:
                        custom_methods_of_the_current_header_ordered.insert(i - 1,
                                                                            custom_methods_of_the_current_header[j])
                    else:
                        continue
```

The code there are 3 lists.
**custom_methods_of_the_current_header** list is getting every matches item and adds inside.   ex ["header01", "header03", "header02"]

**ordered_list** is the list had the ordered item ex. ["mainHeader", "header03", "header01",  "header02", "footer"] ,  as main header and footer are not important, that is why starts range from 1 to 3

**custom_methods_of_the_current_header_ordered** list I am using to add the final ordered list by comparing custom_methods_of_the_current_header with ordered_list, as the ordered_list the header03 should be the first,  then find the header03 in the current header list and adding it in the first index [0, header03]

The code itself works and accomplishes what I need, however, I wonder if I can optimize it to make it look cleaner and reduce the loop and complexity.  Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unlikely we can make a meaningful suggestion from this incomplete code snippet.  And arguably the question isn't on topic for SO anyway.  This would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but make sure to give them enough code for them to answer the question - they'll require working code even if it's just a minimal implementation it has to be complete and runnable.

Comment: Some minor notes: `for j in range(len(custom_methods_of_the_current_header))` -- `j` is only used to index `custom_methods_of_the_current_header`. Cut the indexing overhead and iterate directly over the entries of `custom_methods_of_the_current_header`. | `ordered_list[i].gg.kind` doesn't depend on `j`, so it can be calculated only once in the outer loop and saved in temporary, instead of recalculating the same value many times (involving indexing and two attribute reads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably benefit from removing the multiple inserts and the explicit indexing as follows:

```
custom_methods_of_the_current_header = [
    method
    for method in fmt_data
    if method.get("type") == constants.CUSTOM_METHOD
    and method.get("parent_id") == header_id
]
custom_methods_of_the_current_header_ordered = []
for oli in ordered_list[1:-1]:
    tl = []
    for cmoch in custom_methods_of_the_current_header:
        if cmoch["name"] == oli.gg.kind:
            tl.append(cmoch)
    custom_methods_of_the_current_header_ordered += tl[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight , this solution is great.

Answer (score 0):

This submission does not come with a
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
It would really benefit from one.

When refactoring, we want to keep seeing Green Bars
to instill confidence that our edit hasn't broken anything.

---

Code review remark: these three  names might
be suitable for global (module scope) identifiers.
But they are Too Long for local vars.
Lose the "*of_the_current_header*" phrase.

Prefer adjectives over prepositional phrases when
inventing new names.

---

That first assignment is Too Long.
Yes, list comprehensions are good,
but too much of a good thing isn't.
Consider extracting a tiny helper which `yield`s matching methods,
and then caller just assigns `... = list(_get_matching_methods())`

The nested `for i, j` loops really should be pushed
down into a helper function.
Why?
So we can clarify the
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
with a """docstring""".
As written, the source code is less than transparently clear
about its responsibility.

I *will* note that the `.insert()` call seems slightly worrying.
Maybe it's the best we can do? IDK.
But there's a loop running within `.insert()`,
so we actually have triply nested loops here,
potentially O(N³) cubic complexity.
Sometimes doing a cheap O(N log N) sort,
or using a `dict`, can help out in such situations,
perhaps by using a
[Decorate-Sort-Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)
transform.

Comment: Agreed that the list comprehension is cumbersome but it's likely to be faster than writing a generator and the OP is all about optimisation

Comment: OP included no profiling data, so it's unclear where the hotspots are, but nested loops look more likely. I was focused on: "If we can better communicate these technical ideas to colleagues, then colleagues may be able to notice algorithmic improvements." If elapsed seconds was really the only criterion, then we would have implemented this in compiled Rust which Python calls out to.